# Opening UFO doors

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

[image: The door.]

Somehow, I can't figure out how to open the exterior door of a UFO. I'm pretty sure this thing opens; I've seen enemies open it, and [I've seen Youtubers open it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxYuG5A6k4g). Nevertheless, the usual door-opening controls aren't working. I've tried clicking on the door, and I've tried pressing V, and neither worked. What am I doing wrong? Am I standing in the wrong position? Is this not a door? Am I missing some sort of door-opening technology? I'd experiment, but I'm on Ironman, and I'd rather not risk losing my soldiers to figure this out.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I was standing in the wrong spot. That is a very weird limitation to place on door-opening.

Comment: This is a resonable limitation on "opening doors silently"... Of course, choice of either "silently" or "crashing through" may seem limited :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your soldiers don't want to be standing right in front of a door when it opens onto a room of Mutons and Berserkers.  It's a fast way to commit suicide.  No soldier would open a hostile door while standing right in front.

Comment: @Jeff: Actually, I have soldiers standing in the middle of a doorway if I expect to move them into the next room immediately after I open the door, or if I plan to wipe out all enemies in the room in one turn. It helps snipers and heavies see more enemies to shoot at, and it helps get into arc thrower range for stuns. Also, taking cover next to the door often leaves you vulnerable to flanking.